# Does VCL components have onCreate event?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Need to access some components right after program start but I have found that doing so from form's onCreate event is bad because at the moment they may still be unavailable (access violation occurs). Can not find onCreate event in any component. Am I missing something?

Here is code. Empty form with ValueListEditor.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.ValEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ValueListEditor1: TValueListEditor;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  procedure: Load;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Load;
end;

procedure Load;
begin
    (Application.MainForm.FindComponent('ValueListEditor1') as TValueListEditor)
        .Strings.LoadFromFile('c:\li');
end;

end.
```

Comment: Afaik, that's wrong. When the form's ``OnCreate`` fires, all underlying components are created yet. Do you try to access components on another form or datamodule? Also have you checked the property ``OldCreateOrder = false``?

Comment: Without seeing your exact code we cannot tell you what is wrong with it. All we can do is guess. Please edit your question and provide [mcve]

Comment: A component's `onCreate` event would only fire upon that - but that doesn't mean it's always with the form's creation, too. "_Right after program start_" is also way before **any** form is created. Tell us your actual problem and how we can reproduce it.

Comment: Why do you write the ``Load`` procedure that complicated? Make it a method of the form with only this code: ``ValueListEditor1.Strings.LoadFromFile('c:\li.txt');``

Comment: I guess the AV occurs because the Application.MainForm property is not set yet when the form's ``OnCreate`` event fires!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not because your component hasn't been created yet, because it has been.  The real problem is because the `Application.MainForm` property hasn't been assigned yet when your main Form's `OnCreate` event is fired, so you are calling `FindComponent()` on a `nil` Form pointer.

Since `Load()` is merely accessing a member of `TForm1` then `Load()` should also be a member of `TForm1` as well, and then you can call it, and thus access your component, via the implicit `Self` pointer, which is valid during the Form's `OnCreate` event, eg:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.ValEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ValueListEditor1: TValueListEditor;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure LoadValues;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadValues;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadValues;
begin
  ValueListEditor1.Strings.LoadFromFile('c:\li');
end;

end.
```

If, for whatever reason, `Load()` must be a standalone procedure, then at least have it use your global `Form1` variable, which the call to `Application.CreateForm()` will assign before the main Form's `OnCreate` event is fired, eg:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.ValEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ValueListEditor1: TValueListEditor;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure LoadValues;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  procedure Load;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadValues;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadValues;
begin
  ValueListEditor1.Strings.LoadFromFile('c:\li');
end;

procedure Load;
begin
  if Form1 <> nil then
    Form1.LoadValues;
end;

end.
```

Alternatively, you can fallback to looking for the `Form1` object in the `Screen.Forms[]` array, eg:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.ValEdit;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ValueListEditor1: TValueListEditor;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
     procedure LoadValues;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  procedure Load;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  LoadValues;
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadValues;
begin
  ValueListEditor1.Strings.LoadFromFile('c:\li');
end;

procedure Load;
var
  I: Integer;
  Frm: TForm;
begin
  for I := 0 to Screen.FormCount-1 do
  begin
    Frm := Screen.Forms[I];
    if Frm is TForm1 then
    begin
      TForm1(Frm).LoadValues;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: If I put procedure declaration into private section component on the form are not available inside procedure. E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ValueListEditor1'

Comment: This makes no sense @ALTuser, obviously you did something wrong

Comment: @ALTuser I assure you, the code I presented works. Double check you did *exactly* what I showed. For instance, did you add `TForm1.` to the procedure's `implementation`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the form's onShow() -event.

But be aware, that the onShow() -event is called every time the form is shown, not only the first time.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you should override the `DoShow` method and insert your code there. Since `DoShow` is called everytime the form changes from invisible to visible, you should also add a boolean variable in your form and check in the `DoShow` override, if it is `false`. In that case, it is the first time `DoShow` is called. Then set the variable to `true` and do whatever you need to do the first time.

Please note that within `DoShow` the form is not visible yet. If you need to do something once the form is made visible, you can post a custom message from `DoShow` and put your code in the corresponding message handler. At the time it is executed, the form just became visible.

```
const
    WM_APP_STARTUP         = WM_USER + 1;
type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    protected
        FInitialized            : Boolean;
        procedure DoShow; override;
        procedure WMAppStartup(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_APP_STARTUP;
    end;

implementation    
    procedure TForm1.DoShow;
    begin
        // Form is NOT visible but will soon be
        if not FInitialized then begin
            FInitialized := TRUE;
            // Insert your code here
            PostMessage(Handle, WM_APP_STARTUP, 0, 0);
        end;
        inherited DoShow;
    end;
    
    procedure TForm1.WMAppStartup(var Msg: TMessage);
    begin
        // The form is now visible
        // Insert your code here
    end;
```

Comment: Whenever I've had to use this technique, I would post the message from the Form's constructor instead (thus no `FInitialized` member needed), and it would still work fine most of the time. But, there is a small possibility that the Form's window handle would be recreated after posting the message and before the message is retrieved from the message queue. In modern versions, that can be avoided by using `TThread.ForceQueue()` instead of relying on the Form's window handle at all.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the code I present in my answer has been in all my GUI application for decades, it is absolutely reliable with all Delphi versions and don't need to use any threading which has hidden surprises.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that your code doesn't work. I'm merely pointing out that `OnShow` isn't always the best place to post the message. Also, even with your code, the window recreation issue is still present, albeit rare. I didn't suggest to add threading. `TThread.ForceQueue()` can be called in the main UI thread to delay code that is run in the main UI thread.